# Prolog - readterm

Tags: prolog, predicate

Does anyone know how the predicate `readterm` from Prolog works with facts/database?
I gotta use that but I don't know how to fit it into facts.

Comment: Does this help?  http://www.aistudy.com/program/prolog/visual_prolog/Handling%20terms%20in%20text%20files.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SWI-Prolog, `read_term(-Term, +Options)` reads a term from the current input stream and unify the term with Term, according to the read-options list.